# In MATLAB, equ1 = [x1 2 * x2]', what I get is not what I want. Why X1_ bar,x2_ bar appear?

Tags: matlab

In MATLAB, equ1 = [x1 2 * x2]', what I get is not what I want. Why did you choose X1_ bar,x2_ bar

```
syms x1 x2    
equ1 = [x1 2 * x2]'>= 0
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I use the `.'` to Transpose is get what I want.

Comment: Please remember that the single quote does the complex transpose. You need to use `.'` if you want a true transpose.